# Receiving warning randomly in output

Tags: datetime, terminal, maya, mel

I have created a terminal script, which controls my renders on 20 different machines, it works great, however randomly, it prints out this warning:

`Warning: file: /Volumes/raid/farm_script/procedures.mel line 63: Converting string "" to an int value of 0.`

line 63, that it's referring to, is this line `$time =` `system("date +%s")` `;` in the below function.

```
global proc int getUnixTimestamp() {
    int $time = 0;
    $time = `system("date +%s")`;
    return $time;
}
```

Let's say, 1 in 30 frames print out the above warning, but seeing as that command is just getting the system date, why would it be random like that?

I'm running the above code, from maya running in -prompt mode by the way.

Cheers

Comment: I can't reproduce it. If you just run `date +%s` in the terminal a hundred times does it ever give you the wrong output?

Comment: I don't believe that the date command is the issue here, I believe it's the way I'm calling it, and storing it, but I don't know how to fix it, but no running `date +%s` 100 times in terminal doesn't replicate the issue.

Comment: Can you run that code 100 times in a loop in Maya?

Comment: I can't replicate it from within maya, it's only happening in prompt mode.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I have is this:

```
global proc int getUnixTimestamp() {
    int $time = 0;
    string $timestr = `system("date +%s")`;
    if (size($timestr)) {
        $time = $timestr;
    }
    return $time;
}
```

It only tries to coerce the string `$timestr` to the int `$time` in cases where `$timestr` isn't an empty string.  (Empty strings are what caused the warnings.) Otherwise it just returns `0`.

If you need to do something *important* with the value, rather than just print it for logging, then I shudder to offer you the following alternative:

```
global proc int getUnixTimestamp() {
    int $time = 0;
    string $timestr;
    for (int $i=0; $i<10; $i++) {
        $timestr = `system("date +%s")`;
        if (size($timestr)) {
            $time = $timestr;
            return $time;
        }
    }
    return $time;
}
```

It runs the system call up to 10 times before giving up. It probably won't fail 10 times in a row, but if it does, then it returns `0`.